# How to get result of function in multiple threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to do some works by multiple threading, but the result of that should manage not in threading. for example:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++ )
        {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
                        {
                            var result = Function1();

                            BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                            {
                                Function2(result);
                            })
                            );
                        }
            );
        }

    }

    private int Function1()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        int k = rnd.Next(10, 20);
        return k;
    }

    private void Function2(int i)
    {
        string s = i.ToString();

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        s += i.ToString();

        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
```

by this code, `Function1` execute in multiple threading, and `function2()` do some works with the result value after getting result from function1.

but, when Function1() is execute in multiple threading and changed `result` so `Function2` not work in good way, because the result is overrided. so how can I fix it?
I think I should save the returns value (from Function1) in an array and managed them one by one. is there any better way for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really helps a lot to keep the background work as separate as possible, and avoid side-effects.

So `Function1` shouldn't do anything to change the outside state, and you shouldn't set its result to a field in your form or wherever that is. This should be rather easy to fix.

So, store the result of `Function1` in a local variable, rather than a field. Then pass that variable to `Function2`, and you're done. One way to do that is to use closures over local variables:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
  {
    var result = Function1(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5); 

    BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
      {
        Function2(result);
      })
    );
  }
);
```

Now your background work no longer changes the shared state, and is much safer to be executed in parallel with whatever happens elsewhere.

Just make sure nothing that `Function1` does changes a different shared state. Oh, and be careful even when reading data in `Function1` - it's very easy to read inconsistent data if it's being read and written on different threads.

And of course, this is a rather old way of handling multi-threading and asynchronous code. If you have access to .NET 4.5, you might be better off using the new async/await syntax, e.g. something like this:

```
var result = await Task.Run(() => return Function1(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5));

Function2(result);
```

When you do this in an event handler in a form (or more accurately, inside a synchronization context), it will execute `Function1` in parallel, and push the result value back into the UI thread, ready for `Function2`.

Comment: It didnt work. the result will be the last one. is there another way?

Comment: @Elahe You're not very clear. What last one? This should simply call `Function2` on each of the results you start as background tasks. So if you're only getting the last result, it's because your `Function2` method is overwriting the previous results.

Comment: I edit my question with your answer. but the messageBox show me same value

Comment: @Elahe Actually, your problem is that you're creating two `Random` instances at pretty much the same moment, which causes them to produce identical results. If you fix that, by e.g. using a shared `Random` accesed through a `lock`, the code works fine. Oh, and don't `Sleep` on an UI thread, ever. Not even in dummy code. The UI thread shouldn't be doing any work that takes a noticeable amount of time.

Comment: It worked correctly but is there any way that the results store in Queque not in stack?

Comment: @Elahe The results aren't stored in a queue nor in a stack. They're generated in parallel, and then when you put them back on the UI thread (`BeginInvoke`), they are serialized, in whatever order they happened to call the `BeginInvoke` method (which you can imagine as adding a method to a queue that is read by the UI thread). If you need to process the results in order, you'd have to use more complicated constructs, for example `await Task.WhenAll`. You're the one who needs to decide which parts should be parallel and how to do the serialization. Multi-threading is hard, tough and unforgiving.

Comment: yeah need to process the results in order.. can you explain more?

Comment: @Elahe Well, the question is, are you using .NET 4.5+ or not? The code can be written using `Task` and `await`, or using manual continuations. I'd prefer using `await`, because the code is much more clear.

Comment: Im using .NET 4 @Luaan how can I use await?

Comment: @Elahe Well, on 4.0, it's a bit trickier. You need to use the async targetting pack, which may be a problem if you're using a build server or some tool like that.